How to avoid recomputations of computed properties with SwiftData's @Query in SwiftUI
With SwiftData's @Query macro, I get an array of model items. Then, I use a computed property to group the items. The computed property is used twice in my view and is therefore also computed twice. If the array is long and the operation is complex, the computed property takes a long time to be computed. How can I change my code to only compute the property once and then whenever data from @Query changes?
struct GroupListView: View {
    @Query var persons: [Person]
    
    var grouped: [[Person]] {
        // expensive operation
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("There are \(grouped.count) groups")
            
            List {
                ForEach(grouped) { group in
                    Text("Number of members: \(group.count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to store grouped as a local variable in GroupListView instead of using a computed property. The problem with this approach is that I need to declare the variable in the initializer and the view does not update when persons changes.
I also tried to store grouped as a local variable in body but this causes a recomputation whenever any state inside the view changes and not only when persons changes.

You should make grouped a local var in body. If there are other state in the view, then you should eliminate those state by breaking up your views into smaller views. This is essentially what you have done in the example code you posted. In GroupListView, there are no state other than the query. Do this in your real code too.

In other words, you should do this grouping operation as high up the view hierarchy as possible (views high up the view hierarchy tends to be updated less often), then pass it down to the subviews through their initialisers.

Make grouped a State and use a task(id:) to populate it when it appears and changes

probably best to fallback to CoreData's @SectionedFetchRequest while there is no @GroupedQuery yet. Another way would be to change your model design so you don't need to group it when querying.
